# Why is the navigation bar hidden when I delete "overflow:hidden?" What does overflow do?

Tags: html, css

I started learning html and I'm getting some practice on w3schools.com. I was curious about the `overflow: hidden` line of code. Why does the whole navigation bar go away when I delete it? I thought overflow was just for hiding scroll bars?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floated elements do not add height to their containing element. Adding the `overflow` property gives the containing `ul` height (which is where your background color is coming from). Inspect in your web browser and notice that the `ul` height goes to 0 when `overflow` is removed.

It is because of the background color/ text color that you do not see anything. The nav `li` elements are still there, but you do not see the white on white text. You do not see the grey background because the `ul` height goes to 0.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.spacer {
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.withoverflow {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
      
<div class="spacer">without overflow</div>
  
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="spacer">with overflow</div>

<ul class="withoverflow">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes overflow:hidden does additional task other than scroll-bars. Your ul is not going away, the problem here is you added float to li so ul will not allocat space for floating child(li) if you add overflow:hidden to  parent(ul) it will not allow child to overflow beyond his limit so it will appears, you can try adding border:1px solid red to ul and check so that you can understand this logic.

Also Overflow hidden will hide scroll-bar when it has width and height values.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `float` issue in your code. Since the childs of your `ul` are floating, the parent doesnt expand to include all of them. 
Normally we use to use the **clearfix** method, that allow the parent get the right height, even its children is floating.

The `overflow: hidden;` ou `overflow: auto;` has the same capacity to solved this issue as the **clearfix** method has.

You can understand it better here:

[What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/what-methods-of-clearfix-can-i-use)

**CLEARFIX METHOD**

Create a class `clearfix` with these parameters:

```
.clearfix:after, .clearfix:before {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

Now, just add this class in your parent element that you want to fix. (In you case the `ul`)

Here is a fiddle with your code and working with **clearfix method**:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/vs3Lqt22/

Answer (score 0):

In simple language, it is due to the     float property
So to solve this issue of this without using the overflow simply use the    clearfix property to clear the flow.

Add    class="clearfix" to the    ul
And to the style add

```
.clearfix::after{
content:"";
clear:both;
display:table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code solve the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <style>
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}
li{
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  width:100%;
}

a{
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
.s{
  background-color: red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home" class="s">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In other words provide an explanation for your code. Thanks.